# List of parameters accepted by osm2po server?

Tags: osm2po, documentation

Can someone please point me to the full list of parameters accepted by osm2po server (osm2poService)?

The documentation under "Server" section on osm2po.de seems to be incomplete. For example, findShortestPath is not listed in the "Table of additional service parameters".

Specifically, I am looking for parameter that may have the service return only sum of cost (say total travel time) rather than full list of LineStrings for the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The osm2po service is an analysis tool - not meant to run in production environments - albeit possible.
The cmd-parameters on the help page are almost complete. The server itself is only a dispatcher to several, even self invented, routing and other implementations. Each accepting different parameters. The DefaultRouter e.g. accepts four additional params:

- findShortestPath (true/false)
- ignoreRestrictions (true/false)
- ignoreOneWays (true/false)
- heuristicFactor (0 Dijkstra, 1 good A*)

If you want to find out more, use Firebug or similar tools to see the requests fired by the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that the German instructions have more detail than the English.  Also, another indication could be the file size of the German documentation is nearly twice the size as the English.

When you unzip the program, it creates an osm2po-doc subfolder with the documentation in zip format.  Try browsing the "...de.zip" file.